# How do I upgrade a mac mini from OSX 10.4.11 to 10.6.8

Tags: mac, upgrade, mac-mini

I have an old 2007 mac mini that I am using as a media/music hub, and I'd like to be able to sync it with my iphone. But to do that I need to upgrade its old itunes (v8), but to do that I need to upgrade 2 steps from OS 10.4.11 to OS 10.6.8.
How do I do this?
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe your mac mini supports 10.6 snow leopard. So all you have to do is buy the snow leopard install disc like from amazon (http://www.amazon.com/Mac-version-10-6-3-Snow-Leopard/dp/B001AMHWP8/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1358911973&sr=8-1&keywords=snowleopard), then plug the disc in and do the upgrade.